# Can't use WooCommerceNET after download from NuGet manager

Tags: c#, visual-studio, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm just start coding , this might be a stupid question , after download WooCommerceNET package from Nuget , I can not use it in project , I check the reference , the WooCommerceNET only show up in Assembly-Csharp,maybe this is a problem , google almost 2 hours , still can't find solution , anyone can help? I'm using VS2019 :(
[image]

[image: only find WoocommerceNET in Assembly-CSHARP]

Answer (score 0):

We can see from this page that WooCommerceNET package’s dependency is .NET Standard 2.0.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/WooCommerceNET/

You should choose the correct .NET implementation version if you want to use the WooCommerceNet package.

We can use this table to see what versions of .NET Core, .NET Framework and other runtimes implement .NET Standard 2.0.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support

Comment: thank for answer , but  I am using Unity 2020.3.24f and i check unity api compabitility is .NET 2.0 , still don't know where is the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I need to manually add DLL to my project ! I though download form nuget than you can use it , but you need to add DLL to your project